# Pandas: add elements to index at even intervals

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
             B
A             
0.00    5.7096
7.33    8.0280
25.82  15.7212
43.63  19.5156
55.24  20.1888
```

and I want to add rows with the index at regular intervals (say by 10), so that I can then interpolate the column B with method = 'index'. My desired output is this:

```
             B
A             
0.00    5.7096
7.33    8.0280
10.00      NaN
20.00      NaN
25.82  15.7212
30.00      NaN
40.00      NaN
43.63  19.5156
50.00      NaN
55.24  20.1888
60.00      NaN
```

I haven't found any reindex option that *adds* index elements instead of *changing* them. My best solution is create a new index, append it to the original dataframe, sort and remove duplicates (if any), but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution.

```
step = 10
idx = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index).reindex([round(i, 0) for i in np.arange(df.index[0], df.index[-1] + step, step)])
df = df.append(idx)
df.sort_index(inplace = True)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Effectively do a union by doing an outer join.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""A             B
0.00    5.7096
7.33    8.0280
25.82  15.7212
43.63  19.5156
55.24  20.1888"""), sep="\s+").set_index("A")

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.RangeIndex(0,60, 10)), how="outer")
```

|  | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5.7096 |
| 7.33 | 8.028 |
| 10 | nan |
| 20 | nan |
| 25.82 | 15.7212 |
| 30 | nan |
| 40 | nan |
| 43.63 | 19.5156 |
| 50 | nan |
| 55.24 | 20.1888 |

Comment: seems perfect (solving in just one line), but when I try to change the range to the first and last values of the original index (`df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.RangeIndex(df.index[0], df.index[-1], 10)), how="outer")` I get this error: `TypeError: Wrong type <class 'numpy.float64'> for value 55.24` I guess RangeIndex doesn'g to well with float boundaries...

Comment: `df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.RangeIndex(df.index[0].astype(int),df.index[-1].astype(int), 10)), how="outer")` works,  changes sample data to go against *0.1* then it does insert 0.0

Answer (score 1):

```
idx = sorted(set(list(np.arange(70, step=10)) + list(df.index)))
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

Output:

df
Out[59]:

```
             B
A             
0.00    5.7096
7.33    8.0280
10.00      NaN
20.00      NaN
25.82  15.7212
30.00      NaN
40.00      NaN
43.63  19.5156
50.00      NaN
55.24  20.1888
60.00      NaN
```

Comment: Perfect!!! works fine even if I change 70 in your code to `df.index[-1]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about just reindexing the dataframe? The outcome is identical to the solution you provided:

```
lista = [0.00, 7.33, 25.82, 43.63, 55.24]
listb = [5.7096, 8.0280, 15.7212, 19.5156, 20.1888]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':lista, 'B':listb})

# range(start, stop, step)
# Create new index and increment
my_increment = [i for i in range(10, 20, 10)]
# combine old and new index, here is where you can use the list function to sort them as well
new_index = df.index.tolist() + my_increment

print(df.reindex(new_index))
```

Output:

```
        A        B
0    0.00   5.7096
1    7.33   8.0280
2   25.82  15.7212
3   43.63  19.5156
4   55.24  20.1888
10    NaN      NaN
```

Comment: this is very similar to my solution, creating with a new index that combines the existing and the new values. slightly different (I'm not reindexing) but with a similar amount of code.